# How to hide generated dart files in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Is it possible to hide generated dart files in Android Studio especially `*.g.dart` files?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In **Settings** panel, open **Editor** section, and select **File Types**. Now look for **Ignore files and folders** field at the bottom. Just include `*.g.dart` there and you're good to go!

Comment: unfortunately also disables navigating to those files when for example clicking on a generated class name, hints are also removed for lots of stuff like parameters

Comment: Is there a way to define a toggleable filter in the Project view? It would solve the problem mentioned in the previous comment.

Answer (score 28):

In Project panel, under Options there is a File Nesting Option. I added `.chopper.dart; .freezed.dart; .g.dart` to `.dart` parent. This will group related files under the main file.

[image]

Comment: This is better approach than the accepted answer IMO as it doesn't have the problem pointed out by Merthan Erdem in the comment.